# Как вызвать метод из C# в 1С?

Tags: c#, 1с

Как вызвать например метод `Foo` из этого куска кода в 1С?

```
namespace HelloWorldLibrary
{
    public class Infrascturcture
    {
        public static string Foo() => "Hello World from C Sharp!!!";
    }
}
```

Comment: Для начала, вам надо преобразовать ваш код в COM-объект. Потом надо зарегистрировать его в системе. Наконец, COM-объект можно создать из 1С и вызвать его метод...

Comment: http://www.1csoftware.com/dotnet/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Можно вызвать любой класс с использованием обертки

[Использование сборок .NET в 1С 7.x b 8.x. Создание внешних Компонент.](http://infostart.ru/public/238584/)

Простые примеру можно посмотреть здесь

[Использование классов .Net в 1С для новичков](http://infostart.ru/public/448668/)

Твой код будет выглядеть так

```
врап=новый COMОбъект("NetObjectToIDispatch45");
Infrascturcture=Врап.ПолучитьТипИзСборки("HelloWorldLibrary.Infrascturcture",ПутьКСборке_Или_Имя_ДЛЛ_Если_В_GAС);
Сообщить(Infrascturcture.Foo());
```

Кроме того можно использовать события .Net

[.NET(C#) для 1С. Динамическая компиляция класса обертки для использования .Net событий в 1С через ДобавитьОбработчик или ОбработкаВнешнегоСобытия](http://infostart.ru/public/417830/)

[Кроссплатформенное использование классов .Net в 1С через Native ВК. Или замена COM на Linux](http://%D0%9A%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5%20%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%20.Net%20%D0%B2%201%D0%A1%20%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%20Native%20%D0%92%D0%9A.%20%D0%98%D0%BB%D0%B8%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0%20COM%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20Linux)

[1С, Linux, Excel, Word, OpenXML, ADO, Net Core](http://infostart.ru/public/544232/)

Вот примеры применения

[1C Messenger для отправки сообщений, файлов и обмена данными между пользователями 1С, вэб страницы, мобильными приложениями а ля Skype, WhatsApp](http://infostart.ru/public/434771/)

[Быстрое создание Внешних Компонент на C#. Примеры использования Глобального Контекста, IAsyncEvent, IExtWndsSupport, WinForms и WPF](http://infostart.ru/public/457898/)

[.Net в 1С. Асинхронные HTTP запросы, отправка Post нескольких файлов multipart/form-data, сжатие трафика с использованием gzip, deflate, удобный парсинг сайтов и т.д.](http://infostart.ru/public/466052/)

[.Net в 1С. На примере использования HTTPClient,AngleSharp. Удобный парсинг сайтов с помощью библиотеки AngleSharp, в том числе с авторизацией аля JQuery с использованием CSS селекторов. Динамическая компиляция](http://infostart.ru/public/466196/)

[Использование ТСД на WM 6 как беспроводной сканер с получением данных из 1С](http://infostart.ru/public/525806/)

Ну и до кучи

[Linq to ODATA](http://infostart.ru/public/403524/)

[Code First и Linq to EF на примере 1С версии 7.7 и 8.3 часть I](http://infostart.ru/public/393228/)

[Code First и Linq to EF на примере 1С версии 8.3 часть II](http://infostart.ru/public/402038/)

[Linq to EF. Практика использования. Часть III](http://infostart.ru/public/402433/)

Исходники и DLL можно скачать здесь
http://files.rsdn.org/19608/%d0%a4%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d1%8bNetObjectToIDispatch.zip

1C Messenger выложил отдельно https://yadi.sk/d/G67GAnc-nrUJ9

Обработки для формирования Code First к базам 1С

http://files.rsdn.org/19608/CodeFirstTo1C.zip

http://files.rsdn.org/19608/CodeFirstTo83.zip

Answer (score 2):

Пример можно посмотреть здесь:
[Проверка подписи ЭЦП в файле. Online проверка сертификата используя C# через библиотеку .NET в 1с](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/532477/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8-%D0%AD%D0%A6%D0%9F-%D0%B2-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B5-online-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0)

http://catalog.mista.ru/public/448668/