# Интеграция сайта с 1С в режиме real-time

Tags: sql-server, 1с

Сейчас продумываю реализацию связи между сайтом и 1С в режиме real-time. База 1С на MSSQL.
Пока вижу только один основной вариант это интеграция через SOAP, при добавлении или изменении данных в 1С, отправлять SOAP запрос на сайт. И так же со стороны сайта, отправлять запрос при изменении каких-либо данных.
Кто то предлагает работать напрямую с базой, не описывая сервисы. 
Хотелось бы найти более производительной решение, для того что бы скорость работы сайта не сильно влияла на связь в 1С.
Буду рад увидеть какие-то полезные ссылки, или примеры.

Answer (score 1):

Чужие примеры тут могут сыграть "медвежью услугу". задача серьезная.

Если не можете найти ответ - "посмотрите на требования".

Что я имею ввиду? - задайте себе вопросы:

> - что вы хотите отображать на сайте?
> - что в вашем понимании real-time?
> - насколько оперативно у пользователя сайта должна меняться информация?

Например, пользователь зашел на сайт, втыкает в отчет, в этот момент данные в бд поменялись - как должен повести себя сайт? пользователь увидит обновления только после обновления страницы? или сразу?

В зависимости от ответов на эти вопросы, будет вырисовываться какое-то решение.

Comment: Я думаю эти моменты уже не так важны, т.к. в любом случае отправка данных будет идти на сервер, а о том как их отобразить это отдельный вопрос и в целом он к 1С не имеет отношения. Мы их хоть сразу обновим через AJAX, или после обновления страницы это формальности. Мне самое главное понять более производительный процесс с точки зрения real-time 1C <-> Сайт

Comment: а вы уверены что сайту нужна своя персональная бд? может быть он мог бы пользоваться непосредственно базой 1C?

Comment: 100% Сайту нужна своя персональная БД

Comment: а что в ней будет?

Comment: Кроме данных из 1С, будет ещё очень много чего. Поэтому здесь требование строгое, 1С своя БД, у сайта своя.

Comment: а вариант тянуть информацию о 1С из бд 1С а свою информацию из своей базы вы не рассматриваете?

Comment: просто с тех пор как вы приплетаете синхронизацию между базами, вы закапываете себе "грабли в огороде" если выражаться фигурально

Comment: Как вариант это-то же возможно, такие предложения уже были, я с одной стороны не вижу в этом ничего плохого, т.к. и работа 1С программистов будет минимальной (по сути только предоставление документации когда что-то меняется в структуре). Но с другой стороны хотелось бы понять кто ещё так работал и какие сложности возникли в процессе подобной схемы.

Comment: Я считаю то что вы изначально предлагаете серьезным усложнением, оно может быть оправдано например тем, что например база 1С иногда не доступна, а вот сайт должен быть доступен всегда.

Comment: Именно это я имел ввиду в фразе в самом начале поста, с отсылкой к  требованиям

Answer (score 1):

Я уже давал ссылки [Как вызвать метод из C# в 1С?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/527763/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%b8%d0%b7-c-%d0%b2-1%d0%a1/527802#527802)

Можно выделить стандартные варианты. HTTP и Web сервисы и ODATA.
Нестандартные это прямой доступ через Linq to EF, использование SignalR и рочие web сокеты.

По ссылкам есть большинство. По HTTP сервисам например здесь

https://its.1c.ru/db/metod8dev#content:5756:hdoc:_top:http%20%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81