# Проверка подписи ЭЦП в файле. Online проверка сертификата используя C# через библиотеку .NET в 1с

Tags: .net, 1с

Получаю файл Excel, подписанный ЭЦП. Необходимо выполнить проверку сертификата.
Сейчас у меня проверка выполняется, но почему-то сертификат, который я сам себе выдал, тоже признается верным. Нужно сделать так, чтобы только сертификаты из доверенных центров проходили проверку.

```
СертификатПослеПроверки = Неопределено;
Если ЗначениеЗаполнено(Файл) Тогда
    ДДФайл = Новый ДвоичныеДанные(Файл);
    ФФайл = Новый Файл(Файл);
    Попытка
        Врап = Новый COMОбъект("NetObjectToIDispatch45");
        PackageZIP = Врап.ПолучитьТипИзСборки("System.IO.Packaging.Package","WindowsBase.dll");
        package = Врап.ПолучитьТип("System.IO.Packaging.Package").Open(Файл);
        PackageDigitalSignatureManager = Врап.ПолучитьТипИзСборки("System.IO.Packaging.PackageDigitalSignatureManager","WindowsBase.dll");
        dsm = Врап.СоздатьОбъект(PackageDigitalSignatureManager, package);
        Если НЕ dsm.IsSigned Тогда
            Сообщить("Файл " + Файл + " не содержит подписи");
        КонецЕсли; 
        Для каждого pds Из dsm.Signatures Цикл
            Сертификат2 = Врап.СоздатьОбъект("System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2", pds.Signer);
            Результат = dsm.VerifySignatures(true);
            Если Результат.Equals(Врап.ПолучитьТип("System.IO.Packaging.VerifyResult").Success) Тогда
                Сообщить("Проверка подписи прошла успешно");   
            Иначе
                Сообщить("Подпись не прошла проверку");  
            КонецЕсли;

            Если pds.Signer.Verify() Тогда
                Сообщить("Сертификат действителен");
            Иначе
                Сообщить("Сертификат недействителен.");
            КонецЕсли; 

            Результат2= PackageDigitalSignatureManager.VerifyCertificate(Сертификат2);
            Сообщить("Ошибки: " + Врап.Встроку(Результат2));

            chain = Врап.СоздатьОбъект("System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Chain");
            chain.ChainPolicy.ExtraStore.Add(Сертификат2);// GetYourRootCert() - Ваш корневой X509Certificate2  
            Если chain.Build(pds.Signer) Тогда
                Сообщить("сертификат загружен");
            Иначе
                Сообщить("сертификат не загружен");
            КонецЕсли;

            //////////////// читаем данные сертификата                  
            chain.ChainPolicy.VerificationFlags = Врап.ПолучитьТип("System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509VerificationFlags").AllowUnknownCertificateAuthority;// AllFlags;

            X509VerificationFlags=Врап.ПолучитьТип("System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509VerificationFlags");              
            chain.ChainPolicy.VerificationFlags =врап.OR(X509VerificationFlags.NoFlag);

            chain.ChainPolicy.RevocationMode = Врап.ПолучитьТип("System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509RevocationMode").Online;
            chain.ChainPolicy.RevocationFlag = Врап.ПолучитьТип("System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509RevocationFlag").EntireChain;
            X509ChainStatusFlags = Врап.ПолучитьТип("System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509ChainStatusFlags");
            chain.ChainPolicy.VerificationTime = pds.SigningTime;
            chain.ChainPolicy.UrlRetrievalTimeout = Врап.СоздатьОбъект("System.TimeSpan",0, 0, 30);
            String = Врап.ПолучитьТип("System.String");
            Сообщить(String.Format("Chain revocation flag: {0}" ,           chain.ChainPolicy.RevocationFlag,           0));
            Сообщить(String.Format("Chain revocation mode: {0}",            chain.ChainPolicy.RevocationMode,           0));
            Сообщить(String.Format("Chain verification flag: {0}",          chain.ChainPolicy.VerificationFlags,        0));
            Сообщить(String.Format("Chain verification time: {0}",          chain.ChainPolicy.VerificationTime,         0));
            Сообщить(String.Format("Chain application policy count: {0}",   chain.ChainPolicy.ApplicationPolicy.Count,  0));
            Сообщить(String.Format("Chain certificate policy count: {0}",   chain.ChainPolicy.CertificatePolicy.Count,  0));    

            Если chain.Build(Сертификат2) Тогда
                Сообщить("сертификат загружен");
            Иначе
                Сообщить("сертификат не загружен");
            КонецЕсли;


            Действителен = Сертификат2.Verify();
            Если Действителен Тогда
                Сообщить("Сертификат действителен");
            Иначе
                Сообщить("Сертификат недействителен.");
            КонецЕсли; 
        КонецЦикла; 
    Исключение
    КонецПопытки;    
    Попытка
        Врап.ЗакрытьРесурс(package);
    Исключение
        Сообщить("Закрыть не удалось");
    КонецПопытки;   
КонецЕсли;
```

Comment: Добавь метку C#. Из 1С тебе никто не поможет

Comment: я ставил С, наверно модератор удалил. сейчас попробую еще раз.

Comment: @Albert: C и C# — совершено разные языки. Это раз. А во-вторых, в вашем вопросе нет ни строчки кода на C#, так что я на месте модератора тоже убрал бы.

Comment: @Albert: С другой стороны, вы пользуетесь, кажется, библиотеками .NET, но не говорите об этом в вопросе. Но **вашего** кода на C# в вопросе всё равно не видно.

Comment: @VladD: да, я использую библиотеки .NET как в примере http://infostart.ru/public/417830/ вопрос сейчас поправлю. я здесь впервые, поэтому прошу не судить строго :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1645713/revoked-client-certificate

Comment: @Serginio Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.

Comment: Стараюсь. Просто если TC решил проблему, то ему бы и нужно ответить. Я просто нашел одно из решений. Подошло оно ему или нет не знаю

Comment: @Serginio решение пока не нашел. отвлекают текущие задачи. сейчас посмотрю ссылку. спасибо.

Comment: @Serginio попробовал как по ссылке. без изменений. там говорится что смогли увидеть исключения, а как посмотреть - не указано. может ты знаешь? в журнале регистрации не регистрируется. может лог какой надо вести, только какие значения отправлять в лог?

Comment: Если ты на форме и не установил ВыводитьСообщениеОбОшибке в ложь то должны выводится как в предупреждении ошибки.

Comment: @Serginio никаких флажков нет, сообщения не выводятся. пробовал отключить сеть - проверка выполняется так же.

Comment: Посмотри https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509chainpolicy(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Обработка работает. Левый сертификат был установлен на компьютер в Доверенные лица, поэтому и проходил проверку. После удаления сертификата все отрабатывает как надо.