# Как вызвать статический метод C# в 1С

Tags: c#, .net, 1с

Есть библиотека dll, которая написана на C#. В которой есть класс, например:

```
public class Test
{
    public void TestMethod()
    {
        // Успешно
    }

    public static void TestStaticMethod()
    {
        // Не видит этот метод в 1с
    }
}
```

Обращаемся к TestMethod() без проблем, а вот обратиться к статическому методу TestStaticMethod никак не получается, может кто нибудь подсказать: может так невозможно сделать?

Comment: Я не спец по 1с, а там есть какие-то библиотеки которые вы подключаете к проекту?

Comment: @YuryBakharev да, есть

Comment: попробуйте так https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/native-interop/pinvoke

Comment: не совсем понял, как мне это поможет. Мне надо в коде 1с вызвать код C#. То есть библиотеку dll на .net

Comment: сразу вас не понял. В 1с я не знаю;(

Answer (score 0):

```
врап=новый COMОбъект("NetObjectToIDispatch45");
Test=Врап.ПолучитьТипИзСборки("Test",ПутьКСборке_Или_Имя_ДЛЛ_Если_В_GAС);
Сообщить(Test.TestStaticMethod());
```

Ссылки на нужные ресурсы смотри здесь

[https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/527763/Как-вызвать-метод-из-c-в-1С/527802#527802](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/527763/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%B8%D0%B7-c-%D0%B2-1%D0%A1/527802#527802)